# ASP.NET Get UserControl VirtualPath programmatically

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

I need to get a UserControl VirtualPath programmatically. How can I do it?

For example, MyControl.ascx placed in Controls folder, so the result should be "~/Controls/MyControl.ascx".

Is it possible?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to know the virtual path in your user control's code-behind (e.g. when loading control dinamically) then it can be accessed this way:

```
this.TemplateControl.AppRelativeVirtualPath
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 server.MapPath(@"~\Controls\user control name");
```